# Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I've been using Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC the way I've explained in the below code, but I'm not sure if that is the right and standard way to do it. So I just wanna know if what I'm doing is wrong or if there is a better and more professional way to do it.

```
public interface IService {
    public Boolean AddRecord(Object _Model);
}

public class Employee: IService {
    DataBase Context = new DataBase();
    public Boolean AddRecord(Object _Model) {
        Context.Add((EmployeeModel) _Model);
        return Context.SaveChanges() != 0;
    }
}

public class DataController: Controller {
   IService service;
   public DataController(IService service) {
       this.service = service;
   }

   public ActionResult AddRecord(Object _Model, String Caller) {
        if (service.Add(_Model)) {
            TempData["Result"] = "Data Added";
            return RedirectToAction(Caller);
        }
        TempData["Result"] = "Please try again";
        return View (Caller, _Model);
   } 
}
```

When I wanna use the controller with the DI, I do: (Is this the right way to consume the DataController)

```
public class TestController: Controller {
      public ActionResult Index () {
          return View();
      }

      public ActionResult TestIt (EmployeeModel _Model) {
          DataController DC = new DataController(new Employee());
          return DC.AddRecord(_Model, "../Test/TestIt");
      }
}
```

Comment: You already inject a dependency in your DataController. Just to the same thing to other controllers, I mean, instead of instantiate DataController in your other controllers, just put dependencies on constructor.

Comment: Sure, take a look on my answer below.

Comment: You have the concept down - dependency injection/inversion is exactly what you've demonstrated here. Inversion of Control on the other hand is what you should investigate next. There are many containers that provide this for you - some even plug directly into MVC (we use Ninject for this). Inversion of Control removes the need for you to instantiate your dependencies entirely.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: It might be too much to ask but would you please explain a bit more about what the inversion of control is and how it should be implemented in terms of the example in my question ?

Comment: Sure. If you give me a minute I will type up an answer.

Comment: Answer added. I hope that is of some benefit to you (apologies for how long it took - distractions everywhere tonight!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the general concept of Dependency Injection / Inversion down. That is, you've understood that instead of this:

```
public class Example {
    public void SomeFunc() {
        var service = new Service();
        service.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

..you do this:

```
public class Example {
    private readonly IService _service;

    public Example(IService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void SomeFunc() {
        _service.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

.. and you supply the dependency manually via the calling code.. such as a `Controller`:

```
public HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var example = new Example(new Service());
        example.SomeFunc();
        // .. the rest ..
    }
}
```

So, the first part is *Dependency Inversion*. You have inverted the dependency chain from being top down to bottom up. The second part (the above code block) is *Dependency Injection*.

Notice in the above block of code that the `Controller` has no dependencies injected. This is where *Inversion of Control* comes in.

*Inversion of Control* is a pattern where code completely external to the currently running code decides how it functions. In this context, it means some external code - somewhere else - decides how to supply dependencies to your controller.

(Note, I am quite familiar with Ninject - so the below examples are using Ninject. There are plenty of other available DI/IoC containers available)

Ninject is a framework that can help with this (and many others). Ninject has an extension for ASP.NET MVC which automatically builds and supplies controller instances for you - plus your dependencies.

Without providing a full tutorial on using Ninject (which I will leave as an exercise to the OP to Google), the basics of it is this.

You declare a "module" with the configuration for your dependencies. Using the above examples, your module might look like this:

```
public class YourModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IExample>().To<Example>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

This will wire up all requests for an `IExample` to an `Example`, and `IService` to an instance of a `Service`. So your `Controller` would become:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private readonly IExample _example;

    public HomeController(IExample example) {
        _example = example;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        _example.SomeFunc();
        // .. the rest ..
    }
}
```

The container (in this case, Ninject) looks at your *external code* (the `YourModule` class) and determines what `IExample` should be. It sees that you've said it should be an instance of an `Example` class. `Example` also requires a dependency of type `IService`. So Ninject will again look at `YourModule` and determines that it should be an instance of `Service`. It continues to go down the object hierarchy until it completes the construction of the objects.

Hopefully that makes sense - it is definitely hard to explain these concepts in text.

I haven't viewed this video (I am running off of really really terrible WiFi hotspot while I wait for an internet connection!) so I can't verify it's quality, but a quick Google search turned this up for setting up Ninject and MVC: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_MehI2qBTo

You would definitely benefit from Googling around some Inversion of Control and/or Ninject videos to understand what frameworks like it are for.

It is important to note too that frameworks like Ninject can also control scope. In the example above, I used `InRequestScope` against the bindings. This means that Ninject will instantiate the dependency at the start of the web request - and dispose of it afterward. This removes the need for you to worry about that.

Comment: That Ninject appears to affect the performance (even to some milliseconds) and increase ambiguity in the code, is that right? I already found some posts in stackoverdlow recommending similar approach like by `builder.Registr<IService, Service> (Although I didn't get what the builder exactly is)`, but what's wrong with my approach, I wanna know why people wanna use what you described instead of that.

Comment: Performance - yes. All containers are based on reflection - but most of the cache their lookups (depending on how they construct dependencies). Ambiguity - no. Yes there is some "magic" happening in this setup - but the ambiguity lies in the definition of the patterns. Once you see your controller with the dependencies injected, you know its happening somewhere else.

Comment: Also - what you're doing is essentially the same. The difference between your code and mine is that you're attempting to consume a controller from another controller. With a container, the MVC framework will consume your controller (as it should). Done completely, you will never see the `new` keyword used to instantiate a dependency. Notice your code does that - mine does not.

Comment: One more question Simon, in `YourModel` class you bind the interfaces with a class that has implemented that like `Bind<IExample>().To<Example>().InRequestScope()`, while there's no trace of mapping it to a controller, so when the HomeController is called, how does the Ninject know what class is the HomeController looking for (like I have 100 classes that implement the IService)

Comment: Ninject looks at the parameters in the `HomeController` constructor and uses their types as a lookup. My example is a simple one-to-one mapping. For more complex scenarios (like, as you've given, 100 classes implementing the same interface) the configuration is a little more complex with things such as Named Bindings, rebinding, etc. It really depends on your use case - but its all doable if designed properly.

Comment: I added another sentence to the end of the answer about scoping - yet another important aspect of IoC containers.